# Add to mysql array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have some user preferences I am keeping in an array in MySQL. This is how I get the current array:

```
$array = DB::queryFirstField("SELECT dashboard_array FROM compel_dashboard 
                                           WHERE user_id = %i", $user_id);
```

Which gives me:

```
"s:19:"dashboard-reccomend";"
```

Now if I want to add a new string (`$dashboard_item` contains a string like dashboard-progress) to this array I was thinking:

```
    $array[] = serialize($dashboard_item);

    $query  = DB::update('compel_dashboard', array(
                    'dashboard_array' => $array
                  ), "user_id=%s", $user_id);
```

When I make this call though it doesnt update. The array stays the same as my first call, nothing gets added. If I just update that `dashboard_array` field without trying to add to the array it replaces the value fine so I know its something I am doing with adding to the array.

Comment: Should't $array be a string and not an array to updated the field dashboard_array properly ?

Comment: @vincenth I got it. Below works if you want to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to get it to work. I had to unserialize the array before adding to it.

```
        $dashboard = DB::queryFirstField("SELECT dashboard_array FROM compel_dashboard 
                                      WHERE user_id = %i", $user_id);

        $array[] = unserialize($dashboard);

        array_push($array, $dashboard_item);

        $new_dash = serialize($array);

        $query  = DB::update('compel_dashboard', array(
                        'dashboard_array' => $new_dash
                      ), "user_id=%s", $user_id);
```